# Cannot Parse XML Response in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, retrofit, simple-framework, simple-xml-converter

I cannot parse XML Response in Retrofit 2.0.
I have created pojo classes for that but it stays null even after I get response from the server.

And it throws this error **"java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class"**

Can you help me ?

Thanks In Advance.